# Get the total count of local collection documents using virtual without ref

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I used virtual on Customer schema to get the total number of successful transfer from Transfer collection using the virtual ref of mongoose but i was having issues getting the same for the same collection using virtual.

```
const {Schema, model, Types} = require("mongoose");

const CustomerSchema = new Schema({
    Fullname: {
        type: String,        
        trim: true
    },   
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, "Please enter a valid email address",]
    },    
    PhoneNo: {
        type: String,
        //unique: true,
        //required: true,        
    }, 
   CustomerLevel: {
   type: String,
   enum: ['Gold','Silver','Bronze']
},   
    CreatedAt: {
        type: Date,                
    },
    LastVisitDate: {
        type: Date,                
    },
    
    {
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true,
        getters: true
    },
  toObject: {virtuals: true}
    _id: false
});


//Total Gold customers
CustomerSchema.virtual('TotalGoldCustomer', {
  ref: 'Customer',  
  localField: '_id',  
  count: true,
match : {
CustomerLevel: {
$eq: "Gold"
},
},
});


//Total successful transfer
CustomerSchema.virtual('TotalSuccesfulTransfer', {
  ref: 'TransferCollection',  
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'CustomerID',
  count: true,
match : {
TransferStatus: {
$eq: "Completed"
},
},
});
```

There are documents in the collection but I do not get any count of Gold Customers.

*****OUTPUT
The TotalGoldCustomer always get nothing

***My Expectation

Now I need to get the following using virtual on the Customers schema.

1. Get the total number of users in the Customer collection
2. Get the total number of Customers that are Gold Customer
3. Get the total number of customers that are Silver
4. I want to get the users who do not login in 30 days

Thank you